# Laravel Redirect and Undefined Variabale

Tags: php, laravel

I have made this project that users can see the question on a main page /index 
now I am trying to make it better so that when user type their name after the main URL like:
/index/username 
if that user exists they can see all question but if its not exists they get an error and also i want to redirect user to main page if user not exists. Here is my code:

```
//method for get to index
public function getIndex($author = NULL) {
    //if user not nulll
    if (!is_null($author)) {
        //we get name of author
        $quote_author = Author::where('name',$author)->first();

        if ($quote_author) {
            //set all quote by that name and also set 6 for each page
            $quotes = $quote_author->quotes()->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(6);
        }
    } else {
        $quotes = Quote::orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(6);
    }
    return view('index',['quotes'=>$quotes]);
}
```

and error i get is:

> ErrorException in QuoteController.php line 27: Undefined variable:
>   quotes

Comment: That error message typically means exactly what it says.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$quotes` is not created in every path of the function. You have to make sure the variable is always available.

You should define the variable before the `if` by adding `$quote = null;` or something like this at the top of the function.

Comment: Hi thank You for Your Reply actually i did this before but i got this error:                      Uninitialized string offset: 0 (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\GitHub\cinema-quotes\laravel\resources\views\index.blade.php)

Comment: Could you post your `index.blade.php`?

Comment: as i Said in up now it works its should be: $quotes = [];

Answer (score 0):

I bet you get the error when `$author` is not `null` and there `$quote_author` result is empty. In this case you do not set `$quotes` variable, there is no any dafault value for it. So, you should set default value:

```
public function getIndex($author = NULL)
{
    $quotes = [];
```